# Why did the Rebels oppose the Empire?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I got into an argument today about the role of the Rebel Alliance and the Empire in the Galactic Civil War. My opponent posits the Galactic Empire is not inherently evil, and the Rebels would just be terrorists from their point of view. She felt the oppression and fear of violence they were fighting against were only brought on because of the existence of the Rebel Alliance in the first place.

**Are there specific examples of "evil" actions taken by the Empire unprovoked, or were all their actions "justified" by rebellion?** I tried to bring up [the Antar Atrocity](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Antar_Atrocity), [the Siege of Lasan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Siege_of_Lasan), and Alderaan, but my opponent felt they were justified because the Empire was provoked and needed to keep the peace. I also brought up Order 66, but they argued that was Darth Sidious using the Empire as a vehicle for his whims, not the empire itself.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It was justified to kill a billion non-combantants? Hmm

Comment: Would completely razing Switzerland with nukes just because you suspect one of their leaders to secretly support some "terrorist" group ever be "justified" and "needed to keep the peace" for [the USA/China/Russia -pick your favorite "evil empire"]?